# Sequence from generating function.

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Consider the recurrence
$$\mu_1=1, \mu_2=2, \mu_3=4, \mu_4=8, \mu_5=16, \mu_6=32 $$
and
$$\mu_{n+6} = \mu_n + \mu_{n+1} + \mu_{n+2} + \mu_{n+3} + \mu_{n+4} + \mu_{n+5}, n\geqslant 1. $$
The generating function is $$P(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_ns^n.$$
By looking at the first few terms of the sequence, it appears that 
$$P(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5+s^6)^n. $$
If I can write
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5+s^6)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n $$
then I could show that $a_n$ satisfies the recurrence by induction. It seems that there is a closed form for $a_n$:
$$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^6\frac{x_i^n}{-x_i^5+x_i^3+2x_i^2+10x_1-1}$$
where $x_i$ are the roots of $x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1$. That isn't very feasible, so is there another way to show that this generating function satisfies the recurrence?

For context, $\mu_n$ is the number of ways to throw die until the sum of the faces is $n$. I found the recurrence by inspection, but am not sure how to find the generating function from the recurrence.

Comment: Hexanacci numbers: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001592) and [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HexanacciNumber.html).

Comment: I see, so the closed form for $a_n$ can only be expressed in terms of the roots of $x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1$ - not feasible.